# Should I define a main method in my ruby scripts?

Tags: ruby, main-method

In python, a module doesn't *have* to have a main function, but it is common practice to use the following idiom:

```
def my_main_function():
    ... # some code

if __name__=="__main__":  # program's entry point
    my_main_function()
```

I know Ruby doesn't *have* to have a `main` method either, but is there some sort of best practice I should follow?  Should I name my method `main` or something?

The [Wikipedia page about main methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_function_(programming)#Ruby) doesn't really help me.

---

As a side-note, I have also seen the following idiom in python:

```
def my_main_function(args=[]):
    ... # some code

if __name__=="__main__":  # program's entry point
    import sys
    sys.exit(my_main_function(sys.argv))
```

Answer (score 78, accepted):

I usually use

```
if __FILE__ == $0
  x = SweetClass.new(ARGV)
  x.run # or go, or whatever
end
```

So yes, you can. It just depends on what you are doing.

Comment: This is good advice - this way, your file is usable both as a standalone executable and as a library

Comment: +1 cool. I had a more convoluted way the boiled down to basically the same thing. I'll replace it with this.

Comment: The conditional doesn't work as desired if you're using ruby-prof or the like.

Answer (score 52):

I've always found `$PROGRAM_NAME` more readable than using `$0`.  Half the time that I see the "Perl-like" globals like that, I have to go look them up.

```
if __FILE__ == $PROGRAM_NAME
  # Put "main" code here
end
```

Answer (score 10):

You should put library code in lib/ and executables, which require library code, in bin/. This has the additional advantage of being compatible with RubyGems's packaging method.

A common pattern is lib/application.rb (or preferably a name that is more appropriate for your domain) and bin/application, which contains:

```
require 'application'
Application.run(ARGV)
```

Comment: This is an excellent answer. Place your script in ./bin and add `#!/usr/bin/env ruby` to the top. Then make it executable (chmod +x) and you have something that's well organized and easy to understand.

Answer (score 4):

My personal rule of thumb is: the moment

```
if __FILE__ == $0
    <some code>
end
```

gets longer than 5 lines, I extract it to `main` function.  This holds true for both Python and Ruby code.  Without that code just looks poorly structured.

Answer (score -1):

No.

Why add an extra layer of complexity for no real benefit?  There's no convention for Rubyists that uses it.

I would wait until the second time you need to use it (which will probably happen less often than you think) and then refactor it so that it's reusable, which will probably involve a construct like the above.

Comment: The benefit is that your file can be both a library and a script.  I use this idiom all the time.