# Where should I call a Ruby class method?

Tags: ruby

I have a Ruby method:

```
class ClassOfSomeSort
  def self.methodOfSomeSort(argument)
  ...
  end

  methodOfSomeSort(5)

end
```

I heard calling the method in the class itself is a bad practise.

Where should I call it? In C++ there's an `int main` function where it is done, but where is it done in Ruby?

Comment: You can just write your code (that would be in main) at the ["top level"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9687106/is-there-a-main-method-in-ruby-like-in-c) so to speak. Or you can look at [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582686/should-i-define-a-main-method-in-my-ruby-scripts)

Comment: I failed to see why it is bad.

Comment: As a note, in Ruby method names should be like `method_of_some_sort`, avoiding capitals and using underscores instead. Classes are like what you have there.

Comment: You're getting down voted, most likely because people think you haven't put in enough effort. I'd suggest reading "[ask]" and "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/128421)". I'd also suggest reading some tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby is an interpreted language, so simple program may look like this:

```
print "Hello, World!"
```

And that's all. You can run this program from command line calling `ruby fileName.rb`. In your example you can just call it after the class declaration:

```
class ClassX
  def self.MethodOfMine(argument)
    # method
  end
end

ClassX.MethodOfMine(5)
```

Comment: `Class` is a core object class. Also creating an instance of this class and then calling methods on it means those are instance methods, which they're not.

Answer (score 0):

You can call class methods at any time and in any context:

```
class Example
  def self.demo!
    puts "Hello, world!"
  end
end

Example.demo!
```

This is unlike instance methods where you need to create an instance of something. If you have no instance methods, nor any use for them, instead define a `module` much the same way.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Example
 def self.methodOfMine(argument)
 ...
 end
end

object = Example.methodOfMine(InsertAnything)
```

Call the method outside the class by creating an instance :)